# Internal Error: Failed to find SAX plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have created jar files from MATLAB using `deploytool` when I'm executing program in eclipse i'm getting this error, can anybody help me out..

```
Errors occurred while loading the Settings files. 
Details: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\matlab.settings  
Internal Error: Failed to find SAX plugin.
   C:\Users\ANILKU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ANILKUMAR\mcrCache8.1\javatr0\.matlab\matlab.settings
Internal Error: Failed to find SAX plugin.

There is no Settings files associated with this product node: matlab.
The Settings files may be deleted after MATLAB started up.
Please restart MATLAB to fully solve this issue.
```

I have used java and jars files created by MATLAB so please suggest me any solution

Thank you in advance for suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be Java 1.7 being incompatible with Matlab2013a. The documented examples like computing the FFT worked with 1.7 but mexfiles did not. 
It might work with java 1.6. [Have a Look at the compatibility of release 2013a](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/?sec=glnxa64)